# Node.js How to republish the data.

Tags: node.js, meteor

We have published items based on list ids , we use myLists variable to filter out the List Id, but this variable is not reactive by nature ,when we try to add the new list , then items of new list are not publishing automatically.

```
Meteor.publish('subscription_items', function () {
var userName = this.userId ? Meteor.users.find({ _id: this.userId }).fetch()[0].username : null;

var myLists = [];
var sharedListIDs = [];
SharedLists.find({ shared_with: userName }).forEach(function (list) {
    sharedListIDs.push(list.list_id);
});

Lists.find({ $or: [{ owner: userName }, { _id: { $in: sharedListIDs } }] }).forEach(function (list) {
    myLists.push(list._id);
});

return Items.find({ list_id: { $in: Lists.find({ $or: [{ owner: userName }, { _id: { $in: sharedListIDs } }] }).fetch() } });.
```

Can we have any way to always publish fresh data. Please help me to resolve this issue. any help/suggestion would appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

As [David Weldon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/635981/david-weldon) pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20769721/3068252) to my similar question, what you are looking for is a reactive join. By using the package [publish-with-relations](https://github.com/erundook/meteor-publish-with-relations), I think the publish function you want looks something like this:

```
Meteor.publish('subscription_items', function() {
  return Meteor.publishWithRelations({
    handle: this,
    collection: Lists,
    filter: {owner: this.userId},
    mappings: [{collection: SharedLists, key: 'list_id'}]
  });
});
```

Alternatively, as a (dirty) workaround, you could call

```
Meteor.subscribe('subscription_items');
```

everywhere where you need the collection to be republished.