# Meteor: Reactive Join with "publish-with-relations"-package

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm having the following data structure in my Meteor project:
- Users with a set of list-ids that belong to the user (author)
- Lists that actually contain all the data of the list and a set of user-ids that are allowed to view it (and a owner)

Now I'm trying to publish all Lists of a user to the client with the **publish-with-relations-package** ([Toms version from GitHub](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-publish-with-relations)). Here is a simple example:

```js
Lists = new Meteor.Collection("lists");

if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Deps.autorun(function() {
        if (Meteor.userId()) {
            Meteor.subscribe("lists");
        }
    });

  Template.hello.greeting = function () {
    return "Test";
  };

  Template.hello.events({
    'click input' : function () {
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
        console.log(Lists.find());
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {

    Meteor.startup(function () {
        if ( Meteor.users.find().count() === 0 ) {
               var user = Accounts.createUser({        //create new user
                            username: 'test',
                            email: 'test@test.com',
                            password: 'test'
                        });

               //add list to Lists and id of the list to user
               var listid = new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID().valueOf();
               Meteor.users.update(user._id, {$addToSet : {lists : listid}});
               Lists.insert({_id : listid, data : 'content', owner : user._id});
        }
     });


Meteor.publish('lists', function(id) {

    Meteor.publishWithRelations({
        handle: this,
        collection: Lists,
        filter: _id,
        mappings: [{
            key: 'lists',
            collection: Meteor.users
        }]
    });
});

Meteor.publish("users", function(){
    return Meteor.users.find({_id : this.userId});
});


//at the moment everything is allowed
Lists.allow({
    insert : function(userID)
    {
        return true;
    },
    update : function(userID)
    {
        return true;
    },
    remove : function(userID)
    {
        return true;
    }
});

}
```

Publishing is not working and the Cursor doesn't contain the List element that is initiated.

Any idea how to fix this reactive join for publishing Lists of a certain user? Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Your test data isn't being inserted correctly. Have another look at my solution to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20825758/meteor-how-to-publish-cursor-that-is-depending-on-cursor-of-other-collection). The key difference is that `Accounts.createUser` returns an **id**, not an object.

Anyway, PWR is a bit confusing but I think the correct approach is to publish the user, and then publish `Lists` as the relation. Even though each list document seems to have an owner, I'm assuming the goal is to publish all list documents in the user's `lists` array.

```
Meteor.publish('lists', function() {
  Meteor.publishWithRelations({
    handle: this,
    collection: Meteor.users,
    filter: this.userId,
    mappings: [{
      key: 'lists',
      collection: Lists
    }]
  });
});
```

Give that a try and let me know if you run into problems.