# Meteor: Publishing users from field on own account

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to publish "friends" from the users Collection. There is a field on every account that saves all friend-ids (called addressbook). But publishing doesn't work I'm only getting my own account (as non admin) e.g. if i call Meteor.users.find().fetch() on the console. If I do it the way above the console logs the following:

> I20140107-17:22:38.492(1)?
>   ---------------------------------------[object Object]
>   I20140107-17:22:38.497(1)? [ { _id: 'X6XXyD64AW4CvXG6m',
>   I20140107-17:22:38.498(1)?     createdAt: Tue Jan 07 2014 17:10:43 > GMT+0100 (CET)
>   I20140107-17:22:38.498(1)?     emails: [ [Object] ],
>   I20140107-17:22:38.498(1)?     services: { password: [Object], resume: 
>   [Object] },
>   I20140107-17:22:38.499(1)?     username: 'test' } ]

so no addressbook is presented

Here a snippet of my code:

Server:

```js
Meteor.publish("users", function(){
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ["admin"]))
        return Meteor.users.find();
    else
        return Meteor.users.find({_id : this.userId}, {fields: {username: 1, id_:1, emails:1, addressbook:1, createdAt:1}});
});

Meteor.publish("friends", function(){
    var addressbook = Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}, {limit:1} , {fields: {addressbook:1}});
    console.log("---------------------------------------" + addressbook);
    console.log(addressbook.fetch());

    //return Meteor.users.find({_id :{ $in : addressbook}}, {fields : {username:1, emails: 1}});
```

Client:

```
Deps.autorun(function() {
    Meteor.subscribe("friends");
    Meteor.subscribe("users");
});
```

How do i publish the users which are stored by their ids to the field addressbook (or at least their emails and usernames)? Is there a better way to combine the publish ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your `friends` publish function:

1. You don't really need `limit` when fetching a single document - just use `findOne`.
2. `options` for a `find` is a single object. So you'd want: `{limit: 1, fields: {addressbook: 1}}`
3. A document must be fetched (or you have to use `findOne`) before it's values can be accessed.
4. `fetch` is a function that is available on a cursor (the result of a `find`). `addressbook` is just an array.

It seems like you were otherwise on the right track. Give this a try:

```
Meteor.publish('friends', function() {
  var addressbook = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId).addressbook || [];
  return Meteor.users.find({_id: {$in: addressbook}}, {fields: {username: 1, emails: 1}});
});
```

However, it's worth mentioning that `friends` won't be reactive if the `addressbook` changes. For that you need a reactive join. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753279/publish-documents-in-a-collection-to-a-meteor-client-depending-on-the-existance/) question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I already tried it this way, but it throws an exception on serverside (copied your code), see full log here: http://pastebin.com/0EB4bMZF
I used a console.log(addressbook); and it shows that addressbook is always undefined :/

Comment: You'd get an error if `addressbook` was not defined. I modified to code to deal with that case. If the fetch isn't returning a document with an `addressbook`, then either the user isn't logged in or the user document doesn't have an `addressbook`. Check that `this.userId` is valid and open a database connection on the console with `meteor mongo`. When the db connection is open, run `db.users.findOne(userId)` where `userId` is the one you got from above. See if the document has an `addressbook`. If it doesn't then it isn't being set, which is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Thank you! Now everything run smoothly! There was a old id-entry (that didn't exist any longer) in the addressbook so that was the reason for an exception.