# Meteor publish-with-relations VS collection-helpers for joins?

Tags: join, meteor

What's the best way to do joins in Meteor/mongo? Use one of these packages, or something else:

publish-with-relations

https://github.com/erundook/meteor-publish-with-relations/blob/master/publish_with_relations.coffee

collection-helpers

https://github.com/dburles/meteor-collection-helpers

Answer (score 3):

I'm very familiar with PWR, but collection-helpers is new to me. It looks like the two are complimentary.

PWR solves the somewhat complex problem of publishing documents to the client via a reactive join based on arbitrarily complex relationships. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753279/publish-documents-in-a-collection-to-a-meteor-client-depending-on-the-existance) question for more details.

collection-helpers appears to be a set of convenience functions added to the client to be used when traversing collection relationships inside of a template (given that the required documents have already been published). For example, if you have books and authors in separate (but related) collections, you can immediately get `myBook.author.fullName` inside of a template without having to type out the extra `find` for the author.

Comment: OK got it. Collection Helpers doesn't do anything to reduce the # of docs pushed to the collection. That's where publish-with-relations comes in handy.

Answer (score 0):

currently the top popular solution in atmosphere seems to be  publish-composite https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite

Comment: I think Meteor is soon going to add this functionality to their core supported packages.

Comment: Not that "soon", but they just announced the creation of Apollo, some kind of middleware between the database and the application: https://medium.com/apollo-stack/apollo-8b7215bcab1c. It's based on GraphQL concepts, and therefore  should remove the need for publications/subscriptions. With this approach, joins will be implicit.