# Meteor: having trouble getting the publish-with-relations package to cooperate

Tags: git, meteor, meteorite

I followed the instructions in [David Weldon's post on getting a local copy](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/local-packages)  of `publish-with-relations` since [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753279/publish-documents-in-a-collection-to-a-meteor-client-depending-on-the-existance) informed me the Atmosphere version has a fatal bug.

I put the cloned repo in a directory in my project, `$apphome/localpackages`, and the invocation of `mrt add publish-with-relations` went just fine, no errors.

But then, when I start the whole thing up, it gives me this error:

```
=> Meteor server running on: http://localhost:3000/
W20140219-10:30:46.040(-7)? (STDERR) /home/blaine/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20140219-10:30:46.168(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20140219-10:30:46.169(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20140219-10:30:46.170(-7)? (STDERR) TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'describe'
W20140219-10:30:46.174(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/localpackages/publish-with-relations/package.js:1:44
W20140219-10:30:46.174(-7)? (STDERR)     at app/localpackages/publish-with-relations/package.js:16:3
W20140219-10:30:46.175(-7)? (STDERR)     at /home/blaine/Business/PianoStudio/websitemeteor/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:155:10
W20140219-10:30:46.175(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20140219-10:30:46.175(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/blaine/.meteor/tools/09b63f1ed5/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20140219-10:30:46.176(-7)? (STDERR)     at /home/blaine/Business/PianoStudio/websitemeteor/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
```

It would keep spitting that out over and over again unless you stop the server.

What's going on? Did I do something wrong? Is there something wrong in the [github repo](https://github.com/erundook/meteor-publish-with-relations)?

**Possibly Relevant** I tried this process twice, once using `meteor add` and once using `mrt add`. In between the two, and removed the package with `meteor remove` and cleaned the `localpackages` directory out and re-cloned the repo. Both resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks a bit like you've tried to install it yourself.

Packages need to be installed in `/packages`. The error comes about because meteor interprets your package as part of the Meteor app and not a package, being in `/localpackages`. Meteorite (`mrt`) does all this for you so you shouldn't do anything besides the below:

You can install it in the root directory by simply running `mrt add publish-with-relations`.

To get the package up to date you can then peek into the `/packages/publish-with-relations` and update the code there (its a symlink)

Comment: So what you're suggesting: I call `mrt add`, then I go into `.meteorite/packages/publish-with-relations`, clean out the contents, and repo a fresh directory? Would it be more straightforward to put the repo somewhere outside of my app directory, then follow the rest of the instructions in David Weldon's blog? https://dweldon.silvrback.com/local-packages

Comment: I followed his instructions, but I just put the repo outside of my app directory. You were right that it was misinterpreting it as part of my app! Silly mistake really.