# Reactive joins in Meteor - best practice?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I need to make some reactive joins. I have stumbled across [this hackpad](https://hackpad.com/Meteor-reactive-join-publication-packages-MpSFfsZrMxa) but there doesn't seem to be a clear way to achieve this functionality. What's the best way/packages to perform reactive joins in Meteor?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor.publish: publish collection which depends on other collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398952/meteor-publish-publish-collection-which-depends-on-other-collection)

Comment: Start with [Reactive Joins In Meteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactive-joins-in-meteor/), but I have already answered this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753279/publish-documents-in-a-collection-to-a-meteor-client-depending-on-the-existance) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26398952/meteor-publish-publish-collection-which-depends-on-other-collection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using publish-composite and it is looks good so far.

https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite